# Why and how this exponential brings this cos? And how to operate this absolute value expression?

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$\left|e^{-j4\pi fT}+e^{j4\pi fT}\right|^2 = ?$$

I don't know what would be the result of that expression.

Also I need some help for understanding why this exponential brings this cos:

$$1-e^{j2\pi f}-e^{-j 2\pi f}+1 = 2(1-\cos 2\pi f)$$

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please type up your question and make it self contained.  Links can rot and cannot be searched.

Comment: $\exp(i \theta) = \cos\theta+i \sin \theta$ so $\cos \theta = \frac{e^{i \theta}+e^{-i \theta}}{2}$

Comment: The second is due to Euler’s identity: $$e^{jx}=\cos x + j\sin x$$ where $j=\sqrt{-1}.$ (Mathematicians tend to use $i$ rather than $j.$) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: I have replaced your tag "stochastic calculus" (humor ?) plainly by "complex numbers".

Comment: It is not humor. I'm calculating the potential spectrum of a stochastic wave

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. I would like to know also how to do the resolve the first expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be using the formula :
$$ \cos \theta = \dfrac{e^{j \theta}+e^{-j\theta}}{2}$$

And the fact that :

$$ \cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$$ so $$\cos^2(x) = \dfrac{\cos(2x) +1}{2} $$
First:

$$ \left| e^{-j4\pi fT}+e^{j4\pi fT} \right|^2 =|2 \cos(4\pi fT)|^2 = 4\cos^2(4 \pi f T) = 2 \cos(8\pi f T) +2 $$

Then:

$$1-e^{j 2\pi f} - e^{-j 2\pi f} + 1 = 2-(e^{j 2\pi f} + e^{-j 2\pi f}) = 2(1-\cos(2\pi f)) $$